# Flutter widget state not updating - throws 'Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe'

Tags: flutter

I am trying to implement login/logout in Flutter using [this example](https://medium.com/@kashifmin/flutter-login-app-using-rest-api-and-sqflite-b4815aed2149). Log in works fine and the console output is:

```
flutter: LOGIN WIDGET BUILD CONTEXT:
flutter: LoginScreen(dirty, state: LoginScreenState#552db)
flutter: _ctx:
flutter: LoginScreen(state: LoginScreenState#552db)
```

But after logging out, I can't log back in (the context is lost). After logging out and then trying to log back in, the context within `onAuthStateChanged()` is lost after logout:

```
flutter: LOGIN WIDGET BUILD CONTEXT:
flutter: LoginScreen(dirty, state: LoginScreenState#d112e)
flutter: _ctx
flutter: LoginScreen
```

`login.dart`

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new LoginScreenState();
  }
}
class LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen>

   BuildContext _ctx;

   @override
   onAuthStateChanged(AuthState state) {
      print("_ctx");
      print(_ctx.toString());   
      if(state == AuthState.LOGGED_IN) { 
         print("ready to login");
         Navigator.of(_ctx).pushReplacementNamed("/home");  
      } 
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      _ctx = context;
      print("LOGIN WIDGET BUILD CONTEXT:");
      print(_ctx.toString());
   }
}
```

`home.dart`

```
class Settings extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => new Container(
    child: new ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          new ListTile(
            //leading: Icon(Icons.map),
            title: new Text('About')
          ),
          new ListTile(
            //leading: Icon(Icons.photo_album),
            title: new Text('Logout'),
            onTap: () {
               Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed("/login");
            }
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

The routes:

```
final routes = {
  '/login': (BuildContext context) => new LoginScreen(),
  '/home': (BuildContext context) => new Tabs(),
  '/' : (BuildContext context) => new LoginScreen(),
};
```

Wy isn't `_ctx` updated in `onAuthStateChanged()` and is there a better way to handle login state?

Comment: Sounds like you are passing a stale `context`

Comment: Why do you store context in a local field to begin with ?

Comment: @RémiRousselet The original sample code utilized the local field.

Comment: The localized field already exists in `State` class. No need to make one yourself

Comment: OK. But even just using `context` it fails, as `context` is now null when used in `onAuthStateChanged`

Comment: Did you resolve this? If so, how?

Answer (score 5):

You are reusing an old `BuildContext` instance. Don't save the instance in the `build` method. You should never ever do this.

Your `LoginScreen` is a `StatefulWidget` and it's state (`LoginScreenState`) already has `context` property. Try using this instead.

You also need to dispose the listener, the example already has a `dispose(AuthListener)` method that you can use.

```
@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose(); // always call super for dispose/initState
  AuthStateProvider().dispose(this);
}
```

In general the example is pretty old and I would suggest finding a more recent tutorial. Flutter and Dart is evolving very fast and a 2 year old example is not the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

I was referring the same sample for my app and the problem is no "Unsubscribe" at AuthStateProvider during dispose().  Try to implement something like followings at State:

```
@override
void dispose() {
  var authStateProvider = new AuthStateProvider();
  authStateProvider.unSubscribe(this);
}
```

Comment: When/where is `dispose()` called?

Comment: @Aman There is dispose method in auth.dart, but where should we add this dispose method or unsubcribe code ?

Comment: Thank you Aman, I have successfully implemented the solution, and posted as answer below.

Answer (score 2):

As answered by Aman Chu add the following method in both login_screen.dart and home_screen.dart
It unsubscribes the listener whenever we switch screens.

```
@override
void dispose() {
  var authStateProvider = new AuthStateProvider();
  authStateProvider.unSubscribe(this);
}
```

Also you need to have unSubscribe method on auth.dart which is given below:

```
void unSubscribe(AuthStateListener listener) {
    for(var l in _subscribers) {
      if(l == listener)
         _subscribers.remove(l);
    }
  }
```